# Garbage Collect Spark Streaming Checkpoints

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

With Spark Streaming / DStreams, is it possible to garbage-collect (delete) old checkpoints? (Scala examples are preferred.)

Comment: Checkpoints are automatically deleted for you by the framework. Any reason you want to do so manually?

Comment: So ... the reason for checkpoints at intervals are due to the time it takes to make checkpoints? (Why not checkpoint all the time?) Are checkpoints left around at each crash or non-graceful termination?

Comment: Checkpoints can be set to whichever interval you specify. They are costly as they need to serialize in-memory data and store it to any persistent storage of your liking. If your app crashes, it can be restored using the latest checkpointed data.